# find out which files exists in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have an existing shell script to check whether the file exists or not :

```
[ -f $FULL_FILE_PATH ] && echo FILE_EXISTS
```

I am calling this script from java. But let's say I have 20 files, in that case I am calling this script 20 times. Is there a way that I can call this script once by passing the list of files? In that way, I can skip few extra repetition of this script call.

Comment: You can check file existence inside Java code

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do? Print `FILE_EXISTS` for each file that exists? Once if any file exists and not at all if none do? Or once if all of the files exist and not at all if any don't?

Comment: I want to print the ```$FULL_FILE_PATH``` for the files which exists. @joseph

Comment: [Files.exists()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists\(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...\)) is what you should be using instead of running a shell script from java...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do but you're probably have your own reasons.

**test.bash**

```sh
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    file="$(realpath "$1")"
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "File exist: $file"
    fi
    shift
done
```

In java, you can feed the script with the files that you want to check as arguments.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BufferedReader in = null;
    OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash").redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        out.write("test.bash file1 file2 file3 file4\n");
        out.write("exit\n");
        out.flush();
        String str;
        while((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        int response = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { in.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
        try { out.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```